# Add AmbilWarna Color Picker to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, color-picker

I'm really new to Android Studio

Plz show me how to add this color picker to my Android Studio project, add it as a library to use it

AmbilWarna Color Picker: [here](https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna)

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The page you linked already explains how. If you encounter any problems after trying what it tells you to do, then ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most github projects, they include instructions in the readme to add it to your project.

For Android Studio, simply add the dependency to your app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0'
}
```

Comment: really simple! thank you bro